# jQuery Mobile - Datebox, hide header

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I'am playing with jQuery Mobile - Datebox.

Is there a way to hide header with Android Mode?

I try...

```
<input name="day" id="day" type="date" data-role="datebox"
data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "calShowDays": "false"}'>
```

and

```
<input name="day" id="day" type="date" data-role="datebox"
data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "headerFormat": "false"}'>
//format for header if used %A, %B %-d, %Y
```

But nothing is happened.

Thanks.

Vincent

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.

For http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/,

```
<script>
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
    'overrideHeaderFormat': '',
});
</script>
```

I hope my snippet will be useful to others. :)

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

try this one. it works for me

```
<input name="day" id="day" type="date" data-role="datebox"
data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "headerFormat": ""}'>
```